# change position of wordpress menu items using wp_nav_menu_items

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm adding a search box and a "Join Email List" button to the top of a wordpress main menu. The search box appears as expected, but the email button shows up within the menu's UL -- which I can compensate for with positioning, in the full menu, but it hides the button completely when the responsive mobile menu appears. Not sure how to get it out of the UL properly.

I found that if you require the email button as an external file, it will appear outside the UL -- but that also causes a "1" to appear before the main menu in the NON-mobile version. Puzzling...

Here's my code, with both the string method and require method shown (commented out).

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'main-nav-menu' ) {
        $search_form = get_search_form();
//      $email_button = require_once('emailbutton.php');
        $email_button = '<button id="btn_emaillist">Join Our Email List</button>';
        $items = $search_form . $email_button . $items;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

You can see this live at http://example.wdev05.com/. How can I make the button appear outside the UL so that it's visible in both desktop & mobile, without any strange side effects?

Comment: Actually, with the require_once method, it only appears in the mobile layout in Chrome -- not in Firefox, Safari, or Edge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_nav_menu_items` will add content inside UL.

use `wp_nav_menu` filter to insert content outside ul

```
function _wp_nav_m_filter( $nav, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'main-nav-menu' ) {
        $search_form = get_search_form( false ); // do not echo the form
        $search_form .= '<button id="btn_emaillist">Join Our Email List</button>';
        return $search_form . $nav;
    }
    return $nav;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', '_wp_nav_m_filter', 10, 2);
```

checkout https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L451

Comment: Excellent...now I know. Thank you!